# Zend Session: How set with variable name

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

How do I set the index of Zend Session with a variable name? For instance, is there a way of doing this?

```
$model = new Zend_Session_Namespace('models');
$model::set($index, $value);
```

I want the index ($model->index) to be a variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No problem:

```
$model->$index = $value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = new Zend_Session_Namespace('models');
$model->{$index} = $value;
```

I think this is better.

Comment: Curly braces are only required when you use variables or expressions that return invalid property name. If you have control over these names, it's optional.